# Capture only the error message from validation rule and display in VF page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

i have set up a few validation rules and i have a VFpage using this object. I am able to capture the validation exception and display it on the VF page. The issue is that it shows message as

```
   " Upsert Failed : First exception on row 0: first error;

     FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION Quantity cannot be empty
```

Is there a way i can just capture the error message in validation Rule  "Quantity cannot be empty" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visualforce can do this for you

1. Add the `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag to your page.  (This is the container that displays any error messages if present)
2. Surround your DML call with `try {} catch(DMLException e) {}` (When you catch the exception you won't get redirected to the error pages, but salesforce will automatically create a "PageMessage" for the validation failure.

Comment: It doesnt seem to catch if we have the validation rule error message to show up on top of page. It works if its set the field

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Ralph's post is not 100% correct (see Prady's comment that it won't work for top-of-page validation errors), so I write this answer to clearify.

1. Add  `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag to your page
2. Enclose your DML statement with try catch like this:

> ```
> try{
>
> update account; //or anything else
>
> } catch(System.DmlException e) {
>    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getDmlMessage(0)));
> }
> ```

This will print the first DML error that statement caused which is usually what you want.
You can also try e.getMessage() but this will show additional information (like `Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001L000000QgmomIAB; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION` etc.) which is not user friendly. The advantage of `e.getDmlMessage` is that it prints only the validation rule when the error is caused by validation rule.

Comment: ApexPages.Message and not ApexPage.Message but otherwise this fixed my issue, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this:

```
ApexPages.addMessages(e);
```

instead the user will receive all validation messages at the same time instead of having to work through each one, one at a time.